# Tell IntelliJ IDEA I want library sources for a Scala project after the fact

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have created an IntelliJ IDEA Scala project from existing `built.sbt`. I had not checked the auto-import and download-sources boxes. I regret. Can I tell IDEA that I do want these two options, especially download-sources, without having to delete and re-create the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From the popup-menu in the bottom-left of the screen, select 'sbt'.
- In the newly opened 'SBT projects' window, click the right-most yellow-and-gray wrench icon for 'SBT Settings'.
- Check the boxes 'Use auto-import' and 'Download sources and docs'. Close with 'OK'
- In the 'SBT projects' window, click the left-most button 'Refresh all SBT projects'.
- IntelliJ will refresh and download the sources.

[image]